# Get all Glyphs of a UIFont that have a descender

Tags: ios, swift, core-text, uifont

Is there a way to get all the glyphs of a UIFont that contain a true descender?  It seems that using CTLineGetTypographicBounds is not accurate and returns the exact same descent value for every line.  I thought it would provide the information that I needed but it did not.  So now I am looking to see if I can build a character set from the glyphs that contain true descenders unless there is another way.  The ultimate goal would be able to see if a line of text is below the baseline.

```
  let line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: s, attributes: attr))
  //let's get the real descent test
   var a : CGFloat = 0
   var d : CGFloat = 0
   var l : CGFloat = 0
   let bounds = CTLineGetTypographicBounds(line, &a, &d, &l)
   print("the descent is \(d)")
   print("the ascent is \(a)")
   print("the leading is \(l)")
```

Comment: It's unclear what your original goal is. The code you posted results in different bounds for strings that have no descenders versus strings that do. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: The bounds may be different but the descent or lack of descent is unknown. Meaning is the bounds difference due to upper case or a descender that might be present with “p”. I really don’t care about the bounds.  Just if a descender is present.

Comment: In other words, your question is asking how to detect if a given string contains a character with a descender or not. Is that correct? What's your criteria for a character having a descender? Are you only asking about letters? What about various symbols or Emojis, etc.? Since you seem to be asking about attributed strings, what about subscript characters or other attributed text that modify the placement of letters?

Comment: Well it would be nice to be able to measure the descent of the character but I would settle for just if it has a descender at this point. Descent meaning below the baseline. A comma would probably qualify but that’s why I would like to be able to measure it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it seems that your actual goal is to determine whether a string contains a character with a descender, you can use Core Text to look at the bounding rect of each glyph. If the bounding rect's origin in negative, this means the glyph starts below the baseline. This will be true for characters such as `y` but also `,`.

```
func checkDescender(string: String) {
    let uiFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14) // Pick your font
    let font = CTFontCreateWithName(uiFont.fontName as CFString, uiFont.pointSize, nil)
    for ch in string.unicodeScalars {
        let utf16codepoints = Array(ch.utf16)
        var glyphs: [CGGlyph] = [0, 0]
        let hasGlyph = CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters(font, utf16codepoints, &glyphs, utf16codepoints.count)
        if hasGlyph {
            let rect = CTFontGetBoundingRectsForGlyphs(font, .default, glyphs, nil, 1)
            // print("\(ch) has bounding box of \(rect)")
            if rect.origin.y < 0 {
                print("\(ch) goes below the baseline by \(-rect.origin.y)")
            }
        }
    }
}

checkDescender(string: "Ymy,")
```

You might want to add additional checks to only look at letters depending on your needs.

Comment: great.  would the origin.y also be the distance below the baseline meaning the descender part of the glyph?

Comment: Yes, a `origin.y` of `0` is the baseline. Negative `y` is below the baseline. Positive `y` is above the baseline. The `origin.y` is the where the bottom of the glyph is drawn.

Comment: so I just got to test with another font and even capital letters are drawn below 0 so this is not perfect.  I think I can normalize it per font but just wanted to report back on this.

Comment: It's certainly possible that some fonts draw many characters starting below the baseline. Check the result of some character like `x` and use it's origin as the basis for your check instead of just using 0.

Comment: The issue with checking against zero comes down to what is called in type design an _overshoot_. See [Wikipedia entry on the overshoot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overshoot_%28typography%29). Ideally, you’d want to check against the baseline overshoot as seen on the letters ‘o’ (for the lowercase) and ‘O’ (for the uppercase) and work from there.

Comment: @GrzegorzRolek Thanks. Please see my comment just before yours.

Comment: @rmaddy True, though ‘x’ rarely presents any overshoot, just some selected and for the most part historic designs. The ‘o’ is the safest bet.